# macOS goes crazy: tabs open in new window, applications show up slowly, scrolling is slow

Tags: safari, google-chrome, dock, macos

I am having a very annoying problem which is very hard to reproduce and describe. Sometime, suddenly, my macOS turns crazy. The symptoms I witness are:

1. In the browser (Chrome or Safari) clicking a link opens it in a new tab
2. Scrolling is buggy, jumpy and works only from the built in touch pad. I cannot scroll anymore from my mouse.
3. When opening the applications shortcut on the dock, it opens very slowly.
4. When minimizing a window it falls into the dock very slowly.

I prepared some GIFs showing the happening. I'll try to post them later.

Did anyone else experienced it? Is there any idea what its origin and or how to solve it apart from restarting the machine?

Here's sample: http://gph.is/2oTmpob

## NB

As per the discussion in the comments, seems like [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) is the root cause of the problem. Here's the config I'm using:

```
{
    "global": {
        "check_for_updates_on_startup": true,
        "show_in_menu_bar": true,
        "show_profile_name_in_menu_bar": false
    },
    "profiles": [
        {
            "devices": [],
            "fn_function_keys": {
                "f1": "display_brightness_decrement",
                "f10": "mute",
                "f11": "volume_decrement",
                "f12": "volume_increment",
                "f2": "display_brightness_increment",
                "f3": "mission_control",
                "f4": "launchpad",
                "f5": "illumination_decrement",
                "f6": "illumination_increment",
                "f7": "rewind",
                "f8": "play_or_pause",
                "f9": "fastforward"
            },
            "name": "Default profile",
            "selected": true,
            "simple_modifications": {
                "caps_lock": "left_control",
                "non_us_backslash": "grave_accent_and_tilde"
            },
            "virtual_hid_keyboard": {
                "caps_lock_delay_milliseconds": 0,
                "keyboard_type": "ansi"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `Volume Available Space:   447.7 GB (447655321600 Bytes) (exactly 874326800 512-Byte-Units) (89.7%)`

I don't even know where to start troubleshooting it.

Comment: Thing is this happened to me on two different macbooks (both 2016 13" and 15"). So, I guess this is something more general and others experience it as well. The problem is that it is really hard to describe and google.

Comment: Your gif looks like the slowmo genie effect (shift-click minimized app window in the Dock). Either your shift key is broken or it's activated by accident which would explain 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: @klanomath This sounds like a shift-click case. The question is what makes the shift get pressed. The usual suspect in this case would be [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) which I'm using... Any other idea?

Comment: @klanomath I added the config to the question. It doesn't seem to be problematic...

Comment: That's what I plan next time this happens.

Comment: I used to have a wireless keyboard that would sometimes "press" keys by itself, maybe try using another keyboard and see if it still happens.

Comment: @mtklr this happened to me also on a machine without external keyboard. Thanks.

Comment: OK... So, it happened again and quitting Karabiner-Elements doesn't help.